# What Lord Buddha said about "practicing"?

Tags: karma, buddha, teaching, practice

When we practise some thing, we will get a new skill or improve a current skill. Similar effect happens when we do karma. There is also a result. Is practise another form of karma ?

Is life all about practises ? Will most  of our future depends on our current practises ? Is **KARMA = PRACTISE** ?

I asked a similar question here: [Is understanding a practise ?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/37392/17744). But didn't manage to ask as I want.

Comment: I found this: [Buddha said it's better to travel well than to arrive what does it mean](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/20422/17744). Is this right ?

Comment: Hi! This might be of your interest: [Kamma and the End of Kamma](https://www.amaravati.org/dhamma-books/kamma-and-the-end-of-kamma/)

Answer (score 1):

> Is life all about practises ?

Generalizations are dangerous, but i'd still say that buddhism deals primarily with *reducing defilements*/refraining from behaviors that are not beneficial. At the same time, the noble eightfold path also encompasses attaining new habits.

A summary would go something like this:

- Guard (the risk of unbeneficial habits, not yet established)
- Abandon (unbeneficial habits already established)
- Develop (beneficial habits, not yet established)
- Maintain (beneficial habits, already established)

https://suttacentral.net/an4.14/en/bodhi

> Will most of our future depends on our current practises ?

For a layperson, all actions bear consequences for the future.

"I am the owner of my kamma, the heir of my kamma; I have kamma as my origin, kamma as my relative, kamma as my resort; I will be the heir of whatever kamma, good or bad, that I do"

https://suttacentral.net/an5.57/en/bodhi

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of karma or wisdom solely as a skill.  Neither are something that is added on to us.  If anything, they much more resemble something that is taken away.  That said, yeah, that's pretty close to how one might understand karma from a Buddhist perspective.  Personally, I'd tweak your idea of karma as a "skill" into something more resembling an "orientation".  The more you apply body, speech, and mind in noble directions, the easier those practices become.  Over time, and with deliberation, these behaviors start to become natural wholesome patterns.  We don't practice and get better at doing these things (though that is part of it).  Rather, our very nature transforms in such a way that these positive attributes become our natural orientation.  They require less effort and arise instinctively.  The really cool thing is that it actually becomes harder to behave in less wholesome ways.  Big mind yells at you before you even get a chance to act stupidly.